# Are immediately-called actions not usable in themes?

Tags: themes, filters, actions

If there is a filter or action called *immediately* in a plugin file (not on 'init' or 'wp' action etc.), is it at all possible for a theme to filter it? Looking through wp-setting.php I would assume no, since the functions.php is called way after the plugins.

An example plugin: (Nextgen 2.1.2 does basically this same thing with some of their new filters)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Testthing
Description: Example immediate filter
Version: 0.1
*/

echo 'THE VALUE IS:' . apply_filters('TRYIT', 'SOMETHING');
```

In a theme functions.php:

```
function thing() { return 'something else'; }
add_filter('TRYIT', 'thing');
```

The value is always the original 'SOMETHING'.

Comment: Do you have a code example of something that is called "immediately" ? If it is using "add_hook" or "add_filter", then yes you can capture in your functions.php

Comment: Just added code to clarify.

Comment: I don't think there is way to capture that, but you could try `add_filter('TRYIT', 'thing', 11);`

Comment: I think you'd have to use a must-use plugin to add a filter that early https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins